# Showing span to be in $\mathbb{R}^2$ space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let say $L: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ ($\mathbb{R}$ refers to set of real numbers) and $e_1$ and $e_2$ to be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to disprove that the span $(L(e_1),L(e_2)) = \mathbb{R}^2$ by counter example. Please let me know if my approach is correct here.

By definition, we know that $L(e_1)$ and $L(e_2)$ spans $\mathbb{R}^2$ if and only if $L(e_1)$ and $L(e_2)$ are linearly independent (please let me know if this definition is correct). Suppose function $L$ is as such: $L(x,y) = (5,5)$, then $L(e_1)$ and $L(e_2)$ are not linearly independent. Therefore in this case, $L(e_1)$ and $L(e_2)$ does not span $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Any insights and/or corrections will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, presumably you want $L$ to be linear.  But a constant function is not linear, unless it's constantly zero.

It's certainly not true that the image of every linear transformation of $\Bbb R^2$ spans the whole space.  How about $f(x,y)=(x,0),\forall (x,y)$.